# C# | Program should send an AT-Command to my dial-up modem, but doesn't respond right

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently making a program, which has the function to dial with a Dial-Up Modem.

Information about modem:

**3Com U.S. Robotics 56K Message Modem**

**V.90 ITU-Standard and x2 technology**

The modem is connected over a serialport and my program detects that something is connected on the port. I use for the code C#, WinForms and NET. Framework 3.5 but thats not so important. Normaly when my modem is communicating with a program like the Windows XP Dial-Up Connection Wizard or what i currently use: PuTTY (This will let you send commands over the serialport) these lamps go on(TR and CS) [Modem Lights if connected with PuTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRpKM.jpg). Now when I use my program and i click on the button that will open the serialport and should make an AT-Command, both lights go on but it doesnt make anything and my program doesn't respond. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Windows_XP_AOL
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1" , 9600);
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort.WriteLine("ATA");
            serialPort.ReadLine();
            serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don`t hear a sound or anything. The only thing that is hapenning is that the SD light(Send Data) is turning on for a millisecond and turns off. No command is executed and my program just crashes. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me to get this work? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong :( I hope I wrote my problem correctly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please explain where it crash and what the exception message is

Comment: The program crashes when I click on the button, that sends an AT-Command to the modem. The ReadLine(); makes the program crash but I don't know why. I don't get any error messages except the message that my action has a timeout, which I coded above.

Comment: And the modem doesn't respond to the WriteLine() code cause the ReadLine function crashes the program. If I remove ReadLine, the SendData Light on the modem goes on for a second but i get no response from the modem.