# Program doesn't respond if I send data to dial-up modem

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have the problem that when I send data (AT-Commands) to my Dial-Up Modem my program doesnt respond any more and crashes. I use System.IO.Ports to make this work. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Windows_XP_AOL
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1" , 9600);
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort.WriteLine("ATA");
            serialPort.ReadLine();
            serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

On the modem the Send Data Light lights up and the Read Data Light. But when I click on my button that sends the AT-Command (HAYES) (serialPort.WriteLine("ATA")) then my program just doesn't respond anymore and crashes. Because of my timeout function, it doesn't crash but my modem doesn't execute the command that I'm sending. Does someone know what I am making wrong? I can try to explain with pictures if someone doesn't understand it. Please I need this to work! Thanks for any help :)

Comment: The same (?) question as [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72521635/1911064)?

Comment: The ReadLine isn't seeing the correct character for end of line.  The modem may be returning 0x0d and readline wants both 0x0d and 0x0a.

Comment: Are the RTS and DTR signal line conditions and flow control settings set correctly? Also, have you confirmed the operation with some completed terminal software that is not your program? If it works, check the difference between it and your program and try to match the settings and functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# | Program should send an AT-Command to my dial-up modem, but doesn't respond right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72521635/c-sharp-program-should-send-an-at-command-to-my-dial-up-modem-but-doesnt-res)

Comment: Also: Do **not** do Serial I/O on the Event Thread (blockingly).

Comment: On another Terminal software the modem functions correctly, okay I will try to match the settings somehow.

Comment: "*I send data (AT-Commands) to my Dial-Up Modem my program doesnt respond any more ...*" --  Do you mean the modem doesn't respond to an AT command?  A dial-up modem can be in either of two modes: (a) command mode, which can process AT commands from the attached host, or (b) data-transfer mode, which transmits the data from the attached host, and forwards to the host all data received from the remote.  IOW if the modem is in the data-transfer mode, then any and all AT commands sent to the modem are not processed as commands, but instead sent as data to the remote end.